Magento 2 Magento\Catalog\Model\layer getProductCollection()
I'm trying to update the collection in Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer::getProductCollection() to update de attributes in the layered navigation according with my custom collection.
First of all, when I tried to overide Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer in my custom module, it is not working. Shows me an error like: "The "category_ids_to_aggregate" attribute name is invalid. Reset the name and try again"
public function aroundGetProductCollection(\Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer $subject, \Closure $proceed)
    {
        $categoryId = $subject->getCurrentCategory()->getId();

        if (isset($this->_productCollections[$categoryId])) {
            $collection = $this->_productCollections[$categoryId];
        } else {
            if ($subject->getCurrentCategory()->getName() === 'Sale') {
                $collection = $this->productBlock->getCollectionSale($categoryId);
                if ($collection->getSize()) {
                    $subject->prepareProductCollection($collection);
                    $this->_productCollections[$categoryId] = $collection;
                } else {
                    $collection = $this->collectionProvider->getCollection($subject->getCurrentCategory());
                    $subject->prepareProductCollection($collection);
                    $this->_productCollections[$categoryId] = $collection;
                }
            } else {
                $collection = $this->collectionProvider->getCollection($subject->getCurrentCategory());
                $subject->prepareProductCollection($collection);
                $this->_productCollections[$categoryId] = $collection;
            }
        }

        return $collection;
    }

Can someone help me please? thanks!
I expect to update the facets in the layered navigation to the specific category.
I tried to much in so many ways to update the collection but im not getting to do it.
